# JSON Iteration To Make a List

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate through a JSON to create list.
The code works but for some reason the loop is finished the output is all the data I'm trying to write 25 times. (25 because that is the length of the JSON).

Code:

```
forCounter = 0
sizeCounter = 3.5
json_object = json.loads(json1)
jsonLength = len(json_object["skuAvailability"])

d={}
sizelist=[]
for jsonLength in json_object['skuAvailability']:
  d[sizeCounter]=json_object["skuAvailability"][forCounter]["skuId"]
  sizelist.append(d)
  forCounter +=1
  sizeCounter +=.5

print(sizelist)
```

JSON(json1):

```
{"@type":"ItemAvailability","@context":"http://schema.org","skuAvailability":[{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V7X","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V7Y","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V7Z","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V80","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V81","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":21,"skuId":"1A9V82","exists":true,"backOrder":true,"inStock":true,"maxValue":70},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V83","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V84","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V85","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V86","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V87","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V88","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V89","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8A","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8B","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":21,"skuId":"1A9V8C","exists":true,"backOrder":true,"inStock":true,"maxValue":70},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8D","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8E","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8F","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8G","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8I","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8K","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8M","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8O","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8Q","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0}],"identifier":"nvprod3690049v"}
```

Output:

```
[{3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}, {3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V8
```

Expected outPut:

```
[{3.5: '1A9V7X', 4.0: '1A9V7Y', 4.5: '1A9V7Z', 5.0: '1A9V80', 5.5: '1A9V81', 6.0: '1A9V82', 6.5: '1A9V83', 7.0: '1A9V84', 7.5: '1A9V85', 8.0: '1A9V86', 8.5: '1A9V87', 9.0: '1A9V88', 9.5: '1A9V89', 10.0: '1A9V8A', 10.5: '1A9V8B', 11.0: '1A9V8C', 11.5: '1A9V8D', 12.0: '1A9V8E', 12.5: '1A9V8F', 13.0: '1A9V8G', 13.5: '1A9V8I', 14.0: '1A9V8K', 14.5: '1A9V8M', 15.0: '1A9V8O', 15.5: '1A9V8Q'}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You use one dictionary `d` and populate it for multiple keys (the different values of `sizeCounter`, which is fine.  But you append the same dictionary `d` to `sizeList` every time through the loop, so you get a list with multiple instances of a reference to that dictionary.  Do you actually need `sizeList` at all? Isn't `d` itself the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very confusing and has many unnecessary things in it. The reason you're getting the same data 25 times is because that's how many references to the dictionary `d` get appended to the `sizelist` (because that's how long the `"skuAvailability"` list is in the JSON object).

In Python if's often unneeccesary to use an index like `forCounter` to reference items in a sequence because you can usually just iterate through them directly via a `for` statement. Below is your code modified to do this and create the dictionary. Since only thing in the resulting `sizelist`, it's simply put in it when the list itself is created near the very end.

```
import json


json1 = '''{"@type":"ItemAvailability","@context":"http://schema.org","skuAvailability":[{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V7X","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V7Y","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V7Z","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V80","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V81","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":21,"skuId":"1A9V82","exists":true,"backOrder":true,"inStock":true,"maxValue":70},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V83","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V84","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V85","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V86","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V87","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V88","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V89","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8A","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8B","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":21,"skuId":"1A9V8C","exists":true,"backOrder":true,"inStock":true,"maxValue":70},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8D","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8E","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8F","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8G","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8I","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8K","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8M","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8O","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0},{"minValue":0,"skuId":"1A9V8Q","exists":true,"backOrder":false,"inStock":false,"maxValue":0}],"identifier":"nvprod3690049v"}'''

json_object = json.loads(json1)
d = {}
sizeCounter = 3.5
for availability in json_object['skuAvailability']:
    d[sizeCounter] = availability["skuId"]
    sizeCounter += .5

sizelist = [d]
print(sizelist)
```